# Profile image on view

Tags: html, ios, css, react-native

As shown in the screenshot I want to show profile image on View which hides behind view.  I'm implementing it using React-native.

**Top red view in which add a profile image. under that add another view with shadow.**

[image: Top red view in which add a profile image. under that add another view with shadow.]
**HTML Code**

```
<Content style={styles.content}>
              <View style={styles.topView} transparent>
                <View style={styles.profileImageView}>
                  <Image
                    style={styles.profileImage}
                    source={require("../Images/avatar.png")}
                  />
                </View>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.middleView} transparent>
                <View />
                <View />
              </View>
   </Content>
```

**CSS Code**

```
content: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#f5f6f8"
  },
  topView: {
    marginTop: 30,
    marginLeft: 15,
    width: "100%",
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor: "red"
  },
  profileImageView: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    marginLeft: 30,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: "yellow",
    position: "absolute"
  },
  profileImage: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    position: "absolute"
    // marginLeft: 45,
    // marginTop: 30,
    // borderRadius: 5
  },
  middleView: {
    width: 360,
    height: 346,
    marginTop: 14,
    marginLeft: 15,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    shadowColor: "#B8B8B8",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 10
    },
    shadowRadius: 20,
    shadowOpacity: 1
  }
```

I've already tried **position:"absolute"** and **overlay:"hidden"**. But, nothing works for me.

Hope for better solution. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you played around with the z-index. Give the profle image a higher z-index than the view. A z-index does need a position.

Answer (score 0):

PLease use the z-index property to achieve the above structure.
Note : I have included bootstrap to have a navbar structure. you may totally obsolete it and use the mentioned CSS for your code.

```css
img {
  margin-bottom: -120px;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  border: solid 1px red;
  min-height: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSqrfVof7CYYRtsdCu1VD4AWoPB2gs25PP5hQAuhOwhZngrOhsS" alt="brand"> </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample01" aria-controls="navbarsExample01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample01">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="https://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-md-0">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="text">


</div>
```